# Split paragraph into sentences when paragraph ends with quotes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the whole paragraph into a sentences using Javascript regular expressions.

Paragraph:

`I visited a bar in Kansas. At the entrance I see, "Welcome to the bar!" While leaving that place I see message, "Good night!"
I wondered how they changed the name.`

I want to split the above paragraph into sentences.

1. I visited a bar in Kansas.
2. At the entrance I see, "Welcome to the bar!"
3. While leaving that place I see message, "Good night!"
4. I wondered how they changed the name. (There is a line break(`<br>`) between "Good night!" and I wondered how..)

Currently I am using the regular expression

```
var reg= /(\S.+?[.!?"'] | [.!?] + ["'!.?])(?=\s+[A-Z]|[^<br>]|$)/g;
```

but it is not treating the line break(`<br>`) as a separate sentence. It is splitting the words into

1. I visited a bar in Kansas.
2. At the entrance I see, "Welcome to the bar!"
3. While leaving that place I see message, "Good night!" I wondered how they changed the name.

To create the line break needs to enter Shift+Enter key.

Comment: var array = yourstring.split(".") not working for you?

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, not a string library!

Comment: Actually I need to handle all the scenarios, either sentence will ends  up with either .?!"'. If there a comma followed by " or ' it should treat it as a whole sentence.
Example:

Comment: What about this:`/\.|\"\s\n?[A-Z]/`. Not exactly right, but a little closer (replace \n with br).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understand exactly what you need but this regex should do the trick

```
var re = /(\w[^.!?]+[.!?]+"?)\s?/g;
```

You can see the [matches here](http://regex101.com/r/uV5oV7/2) (note the `g` for global on right side of the regex). I believe it properly splits the matches based on what you want. Let me know if there's a problem.

The code should be something along the lines of (taken directly from http://regex101.com)

```
var re = /([^.!?]+[.!?]"?)\s?/g; 
var str = 'I visited a bar in Kansas. At the entrance I see, "Welcome to the bar!" While leaving that place I see message, "Good night!"\nI wondered how they changed the name.';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: var re = /([^.!?]+[.!?]"?)\s?/g;
This regular expression works good for me. Thank you.

Comment: But what happens when my sentence ends in "?!", "!!", "...", etc.?

Comment: Good point. Adding one `+` should fix them all. Check the link my answer